# HTML elements not being shown after using echo in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am creating a form to update a database and used PHP to query the database and get current values before filling them in as the values already in the input boxes. I used echo to create the HTML elements while inserting the PHP variables however, the elements created aren't being displayed. Here are a couple of the inputs that I tried to make:

```
// Album Price
echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
"<input type=\"number\" step=\"0.01\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumPrice) . "\" name=\"albumPrice\"\n" .
"</div>";

// Album Genre
echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" . 
"<input type=\"text\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumGenre) . "\" name=\"albumGenre\"\n" .
"</div>";
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input elements are not properly closed with a `>` character. This code should work:

```
"<input type=\"number\" step=\"0.01\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumPrice) . "\" name=\"albumPrice\" />\n"
```

Note the `/>` added in the end of the line. (the `/` due to `<input>` not having a closing tag)

Comment: Happens to the best, @James. ('nuff said ;))

Answer (score 2):

There's conflicting quotes in your HTML elements. Use single quotes for `echo()` and double quotes for HTML elements.

Also, you did not close the `<input` tag.

```
echo '<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">' .
'<input type=\"number\" step=\"0.01\" value=\"' . htmlspecialchars($albumPrice) . '\" name=\"albumPrice\" />\n' .
'</div>';

echo '<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">' . 
'<input type=\"text\" value=\"' . htmlspecialchars($albumGenre) . '\" name=\"albumGenre\" />\n' .
'</div>';
```

---

**Tip:** You should turn on [**Error Reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) by adding this code to the top of your PHP files which will assist you in finding errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, if I open and close the php tags multiple times in one document do I need that at the start of all of the blocks of php or just the first one?

Comment: @JamesBurton Just the first one will do